# Wolf or Coyote?

Tags: zoology, species-identification

I took the following pictures in the Yellowstone National Park of a Coyote-like animal. However, when comparing with pictures from the Internet, I see also quite some similarities with a grey wolf. So my question: Is this really a coyote?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that these two species have recently formed a hybrid as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coywolf

Comment: PBS did a documentary about coywolves: [53 minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhtuHXInt88)

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/93010/did-my-wildlife-camera-take-pictures-of-coyotes

Answer (score 15):

It's a coyote - I think it's too slender for a wolf and has [pointed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coyote) ears...

[image]