# Did my wildlife camera take pictures of coyotes?

Tags: species-identification, mammals

A wildlife camera took these photographs of these animals. These are the only pictures my camera collected of them. This picture was taken in the central interior of British Columbia, Canada. The distance from the camera to the subject is a few meters, and the height of the camera off the ground was probably about 50 cm.

I think they're too small to be wolves, and they don't appear to be any of the dogs I've seen in the area. My intuition strongly points to them being coyotes based on pictures, videos, and occassionally seeing them in the light of day. However, I'm hoping that someone can explain why my intuition is right, if it is right.

[image]

[image]

The small coniferous tree beside the road (left of center) is about 50 cm tall.

---

While I generally try to avoid cross-posting, I have started pooling my observations into iNaturalist. These photos can be found as [Observation 110928801](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/110928801).

Comment: They look like coyotes to me.

Comment: Could you see if there are any footprints in that path?
It maybe would be clarifying.

Comment: That would definitely be useful information, but unfortunately I don't have it

Comment: just based on location and probability coyote is a good bet. some way to determine scale would help, such as the height of the short plant on the left side of the picture.

Comment: @John I can go back and measure that plant. I'll update the post and tag you when I have that info'.

Comment: @John I'd say about 50 cm is the height of that plant.

Comment: That makes them barely over 2ft probably less with perspective, that is pretty solidly in coyote size range.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for your perspective, @John !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short Answer

Yes, these are likely coyotes.

### Long Answer

Your options of dog-like carnivores (i.e., [*Canidae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canidae)) in BC include the following:

- [Coyote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coyote) (*Canis latrans*)
- Grey wolf

  - [British Columbia Wolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Columbia_wolf) (*C. lupus columbianus*)<sup>1,2</sup>
  - [Northwestern wolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwestern_wolf) (*C. lupus occidentalis*)<sup>1,2</sup>
- Domestic dog (*C. lupus familiaris*)

  - [Siberian husky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siberian_Husky)
  - [Utonagan](https://petgearlab.com/utonagan)
  - [Tamaskan](https://www.petguide.com/breeds/dog/tamaskan/)
  - [Alaskan malamute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alaskan_Malamute)
  - [Northern Inuit dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Inuit_Dog)
  - [Saarloos wolfdog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saarloos_wolfdog)
  - [Shikoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shikoku_(dog))
  - others...
- [Red fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_fox) (*Vulpes vulpes*)

**Let's start ruling out the unlikely options:**

[I'm not trying to be comprehensive, but rather just pointing out the easiest evidence we can see]

- **Dogs:** Many of these might look wolf or coyote like, but it is *very* unlikely that any of these domestic breeds would be forming wild packs (as is indicated by your image containing multiple specimens). (In fact, it's unlikely you'll even see half of those breeds in BC to begin with!). I'll leave it to you to peruse the links I provided if you insist on examining and comparing their anatomies/morphologies to your specimens.
- **Fox:** Although the largest of the true foxes, this is still a relatively small canine; they typically are less than 20 inches high and 35 inches long [[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_fox#Description)]. Without some measure of scale, we can't be sure, but your specimens certainly look larger than that relative to the tree in the background. More definitely, however, is that *V. vulpes* has a tail that is typically half or more of its own body length. The tail also rests nearly to the ground. The length of tail on your specimens do not match either of these length characteristics. Further, the *very* bushy, white-tipped tail of the fox is not represented by your specimens' *only-somewhat* bushy, dark-tipped tails. Red fox are also typically solitary hunters ([source](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/mammals/r/red-fox/); unlike your shot of multiple specimens).

I know what you're thinking: "duh, get to the wolves vs coyotes already!!"

See [here](https://wildlife.ca.gov/Conservation/Mammals/Gray-Wolf/Identification) for a guide to differentiating wolves, coyotes, and dogs

- **British Columbia Wolf (C. lupus columbianus):** According to [Goldman (1941)](https://archive.org/stream/proceedingsofbi541941biol#page/110/mode/2up)<sup>3</sup> and [here](http://www.cosmosmith.com/british_columbian_wolves.asp), this subspecies of wolf is large with a dark (black with some cinnamon brown color) coat. No mention of a light ventral region is mentioned, which is apparent even in your night-camera shots!
- **Northwestern wolf (*C. lupus occidentalis*):**

  - Their color does not rule them out -- This wolf subspecies is *quite variable* in color and can range from all dark, to mottled grey to all white. (see [here](http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/i13221.pdf) for visual comparison of some wolf colorations).
  - This is potentially the largest of wolf subspecies (27-36+ inches tall at shoulder [[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwestern_wolf)] and 4.5 - 7 feet long (nose to tail tip)! [source:[i](https://wildlife.ca.gov/Conservation/Mammals/Gray-Wolf/Identification), [ii](http://www.cosmosmith.com/mackenzie_valley_wolves.asp)). Your specimen's do not look this large, but they could be juveniles. It would be great to get a height estimate of that plant in your picture or diameter estimate of that tree...
  - This [site](http://www.cosmosmith.com/mackenzie_valley_wolves.asp) suggests that the average pack size is 6-12 wolves, which is significantly more than showed up on your camera (though, obviously this could be coincidence and not a definitive way to rule out this wolf).

This leaves the **coyote:**

- Size: Between the size of the fox and grey wolf: 21-24 inches at shoulder; 3.5 - 4.5 feet long (nose to tail tip) [[source](https://wildlife.ca.gov/Conservation/Mammals/Gray-Wolf/Identification)].
- Color: Gray (or reddish brown), often grizzled, often with **whitish/paler throat, chest, and/or belly**. **Black patches may be seen on the tips of tails** on on feet. [[sources: [Bekoff (1977)](https://academic.oup.com/mspecies/article/doi/10.2307/3503817/2600846)<sup>4</sup> and [CDFW](https://wildlife.ca.gov/Conservation/Mammals/Gray-Wolf/Identification)].
- Anatomy/morphology: [Bekoff (1977)](https://academic.oup.com/mspecies/article/doi/10.2307/3503817/2600846)<sup>4</sup> and [CDFW](https://wildlife.ca.gov/Conservation/Mammals/Gray-Wolf/Identification) compare coyotes to wolves. The snouts are thinner with smaller nose pad on coyote vs wolf, and a coyote's ears are taller and more pointed. Your images, unfortunately, don't really allow us to differentiate adequately.
- Behavior: typically less social than wolves and will rarely travel in groups larger than their immediate family. Even still, they often keep their distance and practice more asynchronous activity. However, coyotes are most **often observed as lone individuals or in pairs** (especially during breeding season)<sup>4</sup>. This matches your camera's image.

  Coyotes are most active in the early evening, but their activity can be variable. Many coyote have become quite nocturnal (especially near humans), but they are known to also be sporadically active throughout the day and showing peaks of activity at dawn and dusk. [sources: [Bekoff (1977)](https://academic.oup.com/mspecies/article/doi/10.2307/3503817/2600846)<sup>4</sup> and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coyote#Hunting_and_feeding_behaviors). Wolves, though, are also active during evening and night...

**Summary**

So, based on the the few number of individuals, coloration, and perceived relative size of your specimens, it seems most likely that these are coyote. If you can get us estimates of height and diameter of the foliage in the background, this could be stated more definitively.

You could always go back to the site and photograph and compare the tracks, too (try starting [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:USFWS_-_How_to_recognise_a_gray_wolf.png) and [here](https://wildlife.ca.gov/Conservation/Mammals/Gray-Wolf/Identification) to compare)....

...

Though of course, it could always be a ["coywolf"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coywolf) (also see [here](https://www.purdue.edu/fnr/extension/coyote-or-coywolf/)) :p.

---

<sup>Citations</sup>

<sup>1. Nowak, R. M. (1995). Another look at wolf taxonomy. *In* Carbyn, L. N.; Fritts, S. H.; D. R. Seip (eds.). *Ecology and conservation of wolves in a changing world: proceedings of the second North American symposium on wolves*. Edmonton, Canada: Canadian Circumpolar Institute, University of Alberta. pp. 375–397. [see map on p 376 [here](https://redwolves.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/13-Nowak-1995.pdf)]</sup>

<sup>2. Goldman, E. A. (1941). Three new Wolves from North America. *Proceedings of the Biological Society of Washington*. 54: 109–113. [See [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Columbia_wolf#/media/File:North_American_gray_wolf_subspecies_distribution_according_to_Goldman_(1944)_&_MSW3_(2005).png) for a map]</sup>

<sup>3. Goldman, E.A. (1941). Three new wolves from North America. *Proc. Biol. Soc. Wash*, 54: 109-13. [available [here](https://archive.org/stream/proceedingsofbi541941biol#page/110/mode/2up)]</sup>

<sup>4. Bekoff, M. (1977). The coyote Canis latrans. *Mammal. Spec*, 79:1-9.[see [here](https://academic.oup.com/mspecies/article/doi/10.2307/3503817/2600846)]</sup>